# General protection fault at reboot

Tags: 16.04, server, reboot

I'm using Ubuntu Server 16.04.3 LTS on a HP Elite 8300 USDT to run a Plex server. The system runs stable since September 2015. Since a few weeks ago, I am unable to reboot the system. Shutdown seems to work fine.

When rebooting, everything seems to go fine, but after the message `[ OK ] Reached target shutdown`, I get a `general protection fault: 0000 [#1] SMP` error and the system stalls.

Here's what it looks like: [image: screenshot] (no logs though since the error occurs after the filesystems are unmounted)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Problem seems to be present in **Kernel 4.4.0-112**. As downgrading to **4.4.0-104** removes my issue.

Try:

`sudo vi /etc/default/grub` and change your `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` to: `GRUB_DEFAULT="Advanced options for Ubuntu>Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-104-generic"`

Include the "quotes". Then do a `sudo update-grub` This should select the default kernel to be something workable for you, provided you have that **-104** kernel as I do. Not knowing when this issue entered the kernel, you may have to play around with a few kernels on your box to see if you have a workable one. Then I guess we wait for the kernel to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I just upgraded to kernel version **4.4.0-119** and the problem seems to be solved. Rebooting my system works fine again.